# Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator - how exactly does it work?

Tags: support

I'm trying to find out how exactly the Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator works:

> Edit and answer 1/50/500 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

So far it seems that the edit hast to be done before the answer, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It seems that the edit hast to be done before the answer, is that correct?

No.

> Let's say that you answer something, *and*:
>
> - You edit the question 12 hours before or after answering it. This allows you to edit now, answer later — or answer now and edit
>   later, when you have the time.
> - Your edit isn't rolled back, or outright rejected if it was a suggested edit
> - The question is not closed for any reason, even simply being a duplicate
> - Your answer has a score of 1 or higher
>
> … then you've done something that we probably want to
> recognize. You understood something, you provided the knowledge that
> you have, and then you provided an *edit* to make sure that more
> people in need of this knowledge can find it, while raising the
> overall quality of the site.
>
> Here's the proposed tiers for the badge (within the above stated
> criteria):
>
> - **Explainer** (Bronze): Answered & edited 10  questions
> - **Refiner** (Silver): Answered & edited 50 questions
> - **Illuminator** (Gold): Answered & edited 500 questions

Note it states:

> **You edit the question 12 hours before or after answering it**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer →Refiner → Illuminator - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%e2%86%92refiner-%e2%86%92-illuminator) by [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post)

Comment: thanks for the link , I only looked searched on superuser meta, my bad. So if I understand correctly if I edit and answer with within 12 hours it potentialy counts. and it gets counted as soon as it gets the first vote. However if the questions gets closed afterwards the count will be undone, right?

Comment: @Albin You've got it! :)